# react flux suspend events vs design change

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I am using react and [flux](http://facebook.github.io/flux/) in my application. We have a grid. It shows country information. If user selects a row in the gird, Based on selected row, I get the country name and set the value in the store. Various listeners are listening to the store for country name change event & as soon as country name is changed, multiple subscribers perform specific task. All this is working fine.

Now as per a new requirement, we need to add a new column in the grid, which will show the country name & the value will be shown as hyperlink. When user clicks on this link, it will take user to a new page.

Problem is when user clicks on the hyperlink, then I need to update the value in store (as country information is changed). once I do that, it actually fires multiple events on current page as all the subscribers who have subscribed for country name changed event will fire.

What alternative I have in this scenario?

Comment: Are you using regular flux? You could pass another argument with the action as something like {emit: false} and then put an if statement around this.emit in your store. Or you could unlisten to the store before you dispatch the action when the user clicks a link.

Comment: @AndrewAxton: yes I am using regular flux. Let me try this. Thanks !!